# C++ Modules on Visual Studio Code on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-code, module

I've got C++ modules working well in Windows Visual Studio, but I cannot get them to work in Visual Studio Code on Windows.
Can anyone help with tasks.json settings and any other requirements to compile C++ modules using G++ and MSVC(Cl)?